# Implement a keyboard click sound, lost

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

Everyone on this site has been very helpful on my schooling of iOS programming, but I've run into a brick wall with a very simple feature.  I've found Apples documentation on implementing the factory keyboard click sound upon a button touch, but what Im not getting is the "creating a sub lass of UIView" part.  I have a very basic calculator that I've built, the buttons are made of standard Round Rect's that I want to make the simple click sound.  So Apple says:Adopting the UIInputViewAudioFeedback Protocol
Perform the following three steps to adopt the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol:

In your Xcode project, create a subclass of the UIView class. In the header file, indicate that the subclass conforms to the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol, as follows:
@interface KeyboardAccessoryView : UIView  {
}

Now I am using the standard UIViewController tied to a xib with all my buttons.  Am i to: Create New File, name it as a subclass of UIView, JUST so i can implement this sound?  That doesn't make sense to me, and if this is really amateur stuff I apologize, but I'm learning from many different places.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your custom input view as the `inputView` property of the object that is supposed to be the first responder (For example, a `UITextField` instance), and the `inputView`(your custom input view) must conform to the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol. And to actually play a click sound: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playinputClick]`.

For example:

```
@interface MyCalculatorDisplay : UIView
// ...
@end

@interface MyCustomKeyboard : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>
// ...
@end

// Then, somewhere in your controller:

MyCustomKeyboard *keyboard = [MyCustomKeyboard new];

MyCalculatorDisplay *display = [MyCalculatorDisplay new];

display.inputView = keyboard;
```