# Play clicking sound when pressing button custom keyboard XAMARIN

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509024/implement-a-keyboard-click-sound-lost) objective c answer to how to do this but I am confused at how to implement this in C# (Xamarin) as it seems in objective c the UIInputViewAudioFeedback is an interface but in C# there is  no interface called UIInputViewAudioFeedback there seems to be a class called UIInputView. How would I go about using this class. There doesn't seem to be a ViewDidLoad method in that class so attaching events to buttons used in the view crashes the app. How would I go about this?

**EDIT:** Here is a little code:

```
public partial class CustomDigitKeyboard : UIViewController, IUIInputViewAudioFeedback
{
  public CustomDigitKeyboard(){}

  public bool EnableInputClicksWhenVisible{
     get{
     return true;
     }
  }

  public override void ViewDidLoad()
  {
      DoneBtn.TouchUpInside += (s,e) =>{ 
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick(); 
      };
  }
}
```

There still is no sound when clicking the button. Is this implementation correct?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has a [IUIInputViewAudioFeedback](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.IUIInputViewAudioFeedback) interface - your custom keyboard view should implement this interface.

Comment: Jason I implemented the interface but this doesn't make a sound when clicked. I have edited the code can you take a look.